# how to display database data in joomla

Tags: database, joomla

I am new to joomlah . So far I have acomplished the following :
1. I have installed it on wamp server.
2. I have created a fewe articles.
3. I have created another  schema on the database that comes with a wamp.

Now, I need to do two things and I wonder what is the best practice
1. Create a template article that will display data in a format
2. Load the data from the DB.

Since a lot of the answers to this question refer to older versions or 2009 answers
I wonder what is the reccomended way to do it today.
(Should I do it with PHP? is there a recommended pluggin? )
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 choices either:

1. Using this tutorial [create a custom component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!1.6) (components are the extension type responsible for displaying content in Joomla's main area)
2. Look through the [Joomla! Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) (JED) for an existing solution - probably start with the "[Tables & Lists](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/tables-a-lists)" category.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Table JX extension for a few years now. It is commercial, though but I think it is worth its money. It has a pretty simple user interface and you can do the basic stuff like to show a database table in an article just by clicking.

Their webpage is not the best, but the demo is quite informative: http://www.toolsjx.com/table-jx/demo